# How to repack a system.new.dat.br with open source command line tools?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, customization, builds

We can decompress a system.new.dat.br and then convert to an img, like this:

```
brotli --decompress system.new.dat.br -o unpacked_system.new.dat 
sdat2img.py system.transfer.list unpacked_system.new.dat unpacked_system.img 
mkdir system && sudo mount -o loop unpacked_system.img system
```

I couldn't find anywhere a way to not mount this. I wanted to not mount this because it needs root, and because inside a docker container is hard, and also because I shouldn't need root to repack system.new.dat.br.

So, how can I both decompress unpacked_system.img, modify its files, repack it and convert back to .dat.br?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount Android 10 vendor image file / how to mount ext4 .img in write mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/1709428/how-to-mount-android-10-vendor-image-file-how-to-mount-ext4-img-in-write-mode)